# Need information for installing WebSphere 8.5 installation

Tags: websphere

I'm trying to install WebSphere 8.5. I downloaded the files from my company internal server and not from IBM portal. I have 3 zip folders for disc 1-3 and an installation manager zip folder()

[image: The image shows all the files I downloaded]

When I install installation manager I need to add a repository.config and I am wondering which repository.config I should add as I have three of them for disk 1-3 and one inside the installation manager zip folder. Am I missing any file? Please direct me to the right steps and resource to install web application in WebSphere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't add repository.config, simply add the path to the single directory you extract  the three zip files to.